# RESTful API - Custom representation of a resource

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

**Example**

There is a system where people submit their leave of absence, and the data are structured like so:

```
LeaveOfAbsence {
   reason: string;   
   from: string; // ISO8601 date string
   to: string; // ISO8601 date string
}
```

Now, when the client requests the resource, it requests the submitted items for a given span of time, and want data to be in one of the following formats:

- the raw data as they are saved in the database in JSON format, or
- lists of all items (also in JSON format) for a specific week/month, etc.,  so each item is duplicated for the span of the absence. (For this representation, `from` and `to` fields are omitted.)

**Question**

In this situation, it seems to be that the requested resource is the same, the submitted items for a given period of time, but it's the representation that is different: raw format vs. view-friendly format.

How should this choice of representation be expressed? I'm thinking a query string (e.g. `spread=true`) could work, but maybe there is a different/better way? (Custom headers?)

(If my understanding of a RESTful API is wrong, please let me know.)

Comment: Take a look at the `Accept` header. It's exactly for purposes such as these.

Answer (score 1):

> How should this choice of representation be expressed?

There are tradeoffs.

If you review the definition of [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), you should be able to see that "information in friendly format" and "information in unfriendly format" can be two different resources with different identifiers.

```
http://example.org/html/interesting-report
http://example.org/json/interesting-report
```

When you do that, however, general purpose components (browsers, caches, etc) are going to assume that these two identifiers are unrelated (in just the same way that they are both not related to http://example.org/html/unrelated-report).

What that means is that, when we send a request that causes one of the documents to be invalidated from a cache -- the cache *won't* magically know to also invalidate the other document.

The other possibility is to treat this as a single resource (one identifier) with multiple representations.  We do this via [content negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4)

The most common form is [proactive negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.1), where the server chooses the appropriate representation to send based on [metadata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3) included in the request.  You might see that in a web browser: when the browser is fetching data for an image, it might include an [Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header describing its preferences for the different image media-types the browser itself supports.

When the server includes a [Vary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) header in the response, general purpose caches can distinguish which requests should receive the previously cached representation of the resource, and which should instead be passed along to the server to obtain a new representation of the *same* resource.

Because all of the representations share the same common identifier, they are all subject to the same [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) semantics.  Thus, sending a successful POST to the resource invalidates *all* of the cached representations.

---

It may be helpful to review this [thread from 2006](https://web.archive.org/web/20150610025808/https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/5857), and in particular Roy Fielding's observations about using separate uri trees for different languages.

---

As usual, the spelling of the identifier doesn't matter to the machines, except in very general terms (for instance, we can use [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) with path segments, but not with the query part).

```
/html/interesting-report
/interesting-report.html
/interesting-report?html
/interesting-report?format=html
```

These are all *fine* -- the [absolute URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3) identifies the document, and general purpose components to not attempt to extract resource semantics from the identifier.  Choice of spellings tends to be driven by other concerns (do we want to support dot segments? what's easy for us to implement? what's easy for operators to recognize in the logs, and so on).